# Using phantomsjs, how to get a value and assign it to an element of an array?

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, phantomjs

The following piece of code when ran produces "undefined".

```
var getList = document.getElementById('lbExercises').option;
console.log(getList);
```

The HTML I wish to get the data from is as follows:

```
<select id="lbExercises" class="listBox" style="height:400px;width:350px;"                
name="lbExercises" size="4">
<option value="1270">Value I want to Extract 2</option>
```

The issue is with my JS code - if it helps I'm running my code by using

```
phantomsjs filename.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the first value of the first option like this:

```
var getList = document.getElementById('lbExercises');
console.log(getList.options[0].value);
```

See jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3LLBS/

This is how you would assign it to an element of an array:

```
var anArray = new Array();
anArray[0] = 123;
anArray[1] = 456;
anArray[2] = 789;

// assign the new value
anArray[1] = getList.options[0].value;

console.log(anArray[1]);
```

See jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3LLBS/1/